# boto3 reads all data in the S3 bucket by paging

Tags: boto3

boto3 reads all data in the S3 bucket by paging.

Now I can only read the default 1000 or set the number of pages.

```
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 300})
for page in page_iterator:
  for file in page['Contents']:
```

```
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME)
for page in page_iterator:
  for file in page['Contents']:
```